# Swift UITextField inside table header

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uitextfield

I have a collectionview with a header that contains UITextField (basically it's a search). I want to update collectionview data on editing this field. The main problem is that keyboard is dismissed after calling collectionView.reloadData(). So i can enter only one by one character per reload. I've tried replace reloadData() with reloadItems() but it doesn't help. How can i avoid this? I know i can put a search field out of collectionView but this is not a right solution for me. (you can check Instagram search followers)

What i did:

```
searchField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldChanged), for: .editingChanged)
```

Then passing this data to my RestAPI server:

```
@objc func textFieldChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
    guard let searchQuery = textField.text else { return }
    if !searchQuery.isEmpty {
        APIService.sharedInstance.searchSubscribers(userId: user.id, token: User.sharedInstance.token, type: segment.selectIndex == 0 ? .followers : .following, query: searchQuery) { (fetchedUsers) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.subcribersList = fetchedUsers
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    } else {
        fetchList(listType: segment.selectIndex == 0 ? .followers : .following, scrollAnimation: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, fixed by setting my search textField as a first responder in willDisplaySupplementaryView

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplaySupplementaryView view: UICollectionReusableView, forElementKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "headerView", for: indexPath) as! SubscribersSearchHeader
        if let searchQuery = view.searchField.text {
            if searchQuery.count > 0 {
                view.searchField.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

not the exact solution but, as a no-storyboard fan, i would add textfield as a subview of collectionView. and have collectionview inset to top as height of searchbar. instead of having it on header.

Comment: Nice solution. But if i set textField topConstraint to collectionView.topConstraint - height searchBar it will automatically put textField to default position after focus